# How to apply Datatables to all the tables in a page atonce?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am developing a website where I have several tables in a single page which have different kind of data and different number of ''s . I have put a class in them called '.tables' and using Datatables(https://www.datatables.net/) I want to apply to all of the table atonce. I tried using:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.tables').DataTable();
});
</script>
```

But it only applies datatables of any one of the tables. Is there a way I can apply datatables to all tables within my webpage.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $('.tables').each(function() {
  $(this).DataTable();
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the tables and apply to each of them.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < $(".tables").length; i++ ) {
   $($('.tables')[i]).DataTable();
   });
}
```

Note tested this.

Comment: I tried it, it only applies to any one of the tables and in console, gives me this error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

If you want absolutely every table to become a data table

```
$('table').each(function(){
    $(this).DataTable();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I realized that i cant use tfooter when using datatables that causes the issue. Removing them fixes the nTf issue.

Comment: Can you help me out with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54899330/how-to-place-individual-search-column-inputs-in-datatables-at-the-head-for-multi

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($('.tables'),function(index, table){
        $(table).DataTable();   
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it, it only applies to any one of the tables and in console, gives me this error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined